# Custom Styled Tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to create custom styled tooltip when hovering on a link.
Google'd almost whole internet and found nothing...
I would like my custom tooltip to have image background that can have transparent background as png image has.

[image]

And some adjustment so the text would appear on that background.
Possible? :>

Comment: You couldn't have googled too much...https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ <- First Google Link

Comment: Not sure if u understand what i meant. Did u see the link provided? I dont want to display "just" tooltip. I want to display tooltip with an image and text over it...

Comment: jquery UI can do tooltips with custom content.  go to @War10ck's link and read up on it - or [here](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but it might get complicated depending on if you want it to be bullet proof, for the easy part:

1. Make a `div` and set the `position` value to `fixed` or `absolute`, give it very high `z-index` and set your image as its background and `display:none` by default.
2. In every link (or any element you want to enable the tooltip for it add some `data` attribute, in this demo it is `data-tooltip-title`.
3. Using javascript, when hovering over the "tooltipped" element, inject the value of the `data-tooltip-title` attribute as the tooltip text, also the `top` and `left` offset of the "tooltipped" element as `top` and `left` for the tooltip, and fade the tooltip in.
4. On mouseout, fade the tooltip out.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/dgxys80b/1/)

```js
var links = $('[data-tooltip-title]'),
  myTooltip = $('#my-tooltip');

links.each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    posLeft = $this.offset().left,
    posTop = $this.offset().top,
    title = $this.attr('data-tooltip-title');
  $this.hover(function() {
    myTooltip.text(title).css({
      top: posTop + 20,
      left: posLeft
    }).fadeIn();
  }, function() {
    myTooltip.fadeOut();
  })
})
```

```css
#my-tooltip {
  background: transparent url(//i.stack.imgur.com/ZNRfI.png) no-repeat;
  width: 541px;
  height: 113px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -999px;
  top: -999px;
  z-index: 9999;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test-div">
  Pie jelly-o chocolate sweet topping jujubes tiramisu cupcake kitkat muffin biscuit. Sesame snaps jelly <a href="#" data-tooltip-title="demo text for custom tooltip #1">halvah caramels macaroon</a> powder cake sweet. Toffee jelly-o halvah. Muffin cake macaroon wafer.
  Chocolate carrot cake chupa chups. Soufflé candy canes cake. Toffee soufflé sweet roll fruitcake sesame snaps brownie jelly-o. Marshmallow dessert biscuit topping gummies gummi bears ice cream cookie
  <br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequatur eum ducimus optio nesciunt <a href="#" data-tooltip-title="demo text for custom tooltip #2">porro delectus </a>nam ipsam voluptatem eaque, tempore voluptates enim? Maxime amet quas
  unde eligendi recusandae esse cum?
</div>
<div id="my-tooltip"></div>
```

---

The above custom tooltip will not work perfectly when:

- The distance between "tooltipped" and the very right or bottom sides of the browser window is *less* than the width of the tooltip.
- The text of the "tooltipped" element is wrapped on two lines.
- The text of the tooltip is longer than the tooltip width.

These issues could be fixed but it needs further implementations.

Comment: That's very nice to start with and it is the thing i needed ;D Thanks mate <3

Comment: However, do u have an idea how could i add new lines there (beside the title) ? Like data-tooltip-line1 and data-tooltip-line2 ?

Answer (score 0):

An HTML `title` attribute (what is normally considered a "tool-tip") can only be text.  To do what you want, take a look at Bootstrap "Popovers": http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: and what about some css/js tooltips that can contains images? i would really like to not use bootstrap for only tooltips. Any jsfiddle example would be awesome ;D